# Is there a way to set precision for the function st_linestring?

Tags: r, r-sf

I am converting a matrix to a linestring using the sf library function st_linestring. When I use this function on the matrix it rounds the values to 7 digits. I need significance up to 6 decimal places regardless of how many digits there are. For example the number 109.319272 is rounded to 109.319300.

Here are the two matrices:

```
> testFt
          [,1]    [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] 353367.5 1228429   0.000000
 [2,] 353363.2 1228428   4.332678
 [3,] 353359.3 1228433  10.712694
 [4,] 353356.0 1228438  16.029563
 [5,] 353358.1 1228451  29.364214
 [6,] 353366.3 1228469  49.616436
 [7,] 353383.1 1228461  68.395384
 [8,] 353382.9 1228443  86.336387
 [9,] 353374.4 1228429 102.443063
[10,] 353367.5 1228429 109.319272
> st_coordinates(helperTest)
             X       Y          M L1
 [1,] 353367.5 1228429   0.000000  1
 [2,] 353363.2 1228428   4.332678  1
 [3,] 353359.3 1228433  10.712690  1
 [4,] 353356.0 1228438  16.029560  1
 [5,] 353358.1 1228451  29.364210  1
 [6,] 353366.3 1228469  49.616440  1
 [7,] 353383.1 1228461  68.395380  1
 [8,] 353382.9 1228443  86.336390  1
 [9,] 353374.4 1228429 102.443100  1
[10,] 353367.5 1228429 109.319300  1
```

The first matrix has the correct precision. The second matrix results from transforming the first into a linestring using st_linestring. I then converted the linestring into an sf object to easily show the matrix using st_coordinates however, if you just print out the linestring you can see the values in the 3rd column are rounded. Is there a way to set the precision of st_linestring so my values will have 6 decimals of significance like the first matrix?

Comment: I can't replicate this. Tests creating XYM linestrings and converting back via `st_coordinates` don't lose any precision for me. What's your code that goes from `testFt` to `helperTest`?

Comment: @Spacedman You can see the loss in precision from simply converting testFt to a linestring by 
 using st_linestring.  `testFt <- st_linestring(testFt, dim = "XYM")` Then simply calling `testFt` will print out the linestring and the loss in precision can be seen.  `LINESTRING M (353367.5 1228429 0, 353363.2 1228428 4.332678, 353359.3 1228433 10.71269, 353356 1228438 16.02956, 353358.1 1228451 29.36421, 353366.3 1228469 49.61644, 353383.1 1228461 68.39538, 353382.9 1228443 86.33639, 353374.4 1228429 102.4431, 353367.5 1228429 109.3193)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some test data I cannot replicate this.

Make a 3x10 matrix:

```
> testFt = matrix(runif(30),ncol=3)
> testFt
            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] 0.89427444 0.9614064 0.03305242
 [2,] 0.64785749 0.2379120 0.76285818
 [3,] 0.18872965 0.3535477 0.19718624
 [4,] 0.21516340 0.4436407 0.36707556
 [5,] 0.85731714 0.4872524 0.46147387
 [6,] 0.98970232 0.6678123 0.76021971
 [7,] 0.16932569 0.1547750 0.16983325
 [8,] 0.18255042 0.7313963 0.60732292
 [9,] 0.03580905 0.4369531 0.32653902
[10,] 0.21047936 0.4164918 0.40285367
```

Convert to a LINESTRING:

```
> testFtPts = st_linestring(testFt, dim="XYM")

> testFtPts
LINESTRING M (0.8942744 0.9614064 0.03305242, 0.6478575 0.237912 0.7628582, 0.1887296 0.3535477 0.1971862, 0.2151634 0.4436407 0.3670756, 0.8573171 0.4872524 0.4614739, 0.9897023 0.6678123 0.7602197, 0.1693257 0.154775 0.1698332, 0.1825504 0.7313963 0.6073229, 0.03580905 0.4369531 0.326539, 0.2104794 0.4164918 0.4028537)
```

Any apparent loss in precision there is due to display truncation rather than actual rounding of the value. If I convert to coordinates:

```
> testFtPtsCoord = st_coordinates(testFtPts)
> testFtPtsCoord
               X         Y          M L1
 [1,] 0.89427444 0.9614064 0.03305242  1
 [2,] 0.64785749 0.2379120 0.76285818  1
 [3,] 0.18872965 0.3535477 0.19718624  1
 [4,] 0.21516340 0.4436407 0.36707556  1
 [5,] 0.85731714 0.4872524 0.46147387  1
 [6,] 0.98970232 0.6678123 0.76021971  1
 [7,] 0.16932569 0.1547750 0.16983325  1
 [8,] 0.18255042 0.7313963 0.60732292  1
 [9,] 0.03580905 0.4369531 0.32653902  1
[10,] 0.21047936 0.4164918 0.40285367  1
```

The values are all identical:

```
> all(testFt == testFtPtsCoord[,1:3])
[1] TRUE
```

I've even tried it with numbers in the same rough range as your data:

```
> set.seed(99)
> testFt = cbind(runif(10,353300,353400),runif(10,1228400, 1228500), runif(10, 0, 100))
> testFt
          [,1]    [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] 353358.5 1228455 22.7903474
 [2,] 353311.4 1228451  8.0524150
 [3,] 353368.4 1228419 82.1618422
 [4,] 353399.3 1228464 59.1113977
 [5,] 353353.5 1228469 77.3389019
 [6,] 353396.7 1228464 35.0085977
 [7,] 353367.1 1228436  0.6061323
 [8,] 353329.5 1228410 81.4506223
 [9,] 353335.8 1228410  0.1179229
[10,] 353317.5 1228418 20.0690183

> testFtPts = st_linestring(testFt, dim="XYM")
> testFtPtsCoord = st_coordinates(testFtPts)
> all(testFt == testFtPtsCoord[,1:3])
[1] TRUE
>
```

Assuming this is how you are going from matrix to lines to matrix again I can't replicate any loss in precision.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. It makes much more sense now that the apparent loss in precision from st_linestring is just display truncation. The values must have been actually rounded when I tried converting the linestring back into an sf object.